USBASP programmer problem
I just made a USBASP programmer following the structure on the internet,
I'm using ATMEGA8A as my programmer IC, my problem is that when I connect the USB cable to my
PC it says the USB device does not recognized, but weirdly when I press the target reset button(GROUND it I mean)
which is placed on PB2 of my ATMEGA8A it recognizes my programmer and as long as I'm pressing it ,it recognizes my programmer but once I release the button again the "USB device does not recognized" message shows up, and imagine you always have to press your target IC reset button so that you can program it, it's not normal and in my PCB programmer directly is connected to ATMEGA128,
is there anyone who can help me on this, I leave the schematic of programmer down below

